# How to insert 10 rows for each Id in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created loop for inserting data into a table 10 times with ProjectId hardcoded
And my code looks something like this

```
DECLARE @IndexNumber INT
SELECT @IndexNumber  = 1

WHILE @OrderIndex >=1 AND @OrderIndex <= 10
    BEGIN
         INSERT INTO [tablename] (@IndexNumber [a], [b], [c], [ProjectId])
         VALUES (a, b, c, 50)
         SELECT @IndexNumber = @IndexNumber + 1
    END
```

But now i want create a loop to insert same data but with ProjectId value incrementing after inserting ten rows
for exapmple:

ten rows with a, b, c,  50

ten rows with a, b, c,  51

ten rows with a, b, c,  53

ten rows with a, b, c,  54

...

Comment: So each 10 rows exactly the same, starting from 50 going to 54?

Comment: Have you run your scpipt? What is the result?

Comment: starting from 50 going to 80, everything the same exepct ProjectId

Comment: Note, however, that a `WHILE` loop would be the slowest method (by far) to achieve this. SQL is a set based language and so set based solutions are significantly faster. Iterative solutions, in SQL, are often *very* slow.

Comment: You're putting identical rows in the table? Or do you have a unique identity key or something?

Comment: everything identical except ProjectId value, it should be different

Answer (score 1):

YOu'd be far better off here with a Tally that a `WHILE` loop here. As I mentioned in my comment, SQL is a set based language and so set based solutions are significantly faster. Iterative solutions, in SQL, are often *very* slow.

Based on the description (not the SQL) in your question, then something like this will likely work:

```sql
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (1000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I --Change TOP clause to needed number of rows
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3) --1,000 rows, add more cross joins for more rows
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (a,b,c,I)
SELECT 'a','b','c', (I / 10) + 50 AS I
FROM Tally;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used nested while loop. therefore the query does not have the best performance, but the query works perfectly.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
    col1 NVARCHAR(2),
    col2 NVARCHAR(2),
    col3 NVARCHAR(2),
    ProjectID INT
)

DECLARE @inc1 INT = 1, @inc2 INT = 1, @ProjectID INT = 50

WHILE @inc1 <= 5
BEGIN
    WHILE @inc2 <= 10
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @tbl
            VALUES ('a','b', 'c', @ProjectID)

            SET @inc2 = @inc2 + 1
        END

    SET @inc1 = @inc1 + 1
    SET @inc2 = 1
    SET @ProjectID = @ProjectID + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

Check output on [DB FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3116addea69454b1cc2bf3f5ba8ad962)